# <div id="variable"></div> as value inside input text?

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Weight" value="<div id="variable"></div>">
```

I have this code. I want the value from "weight" to get the content of `<div id="variable"></div>` which is generated with jquery. It is a number like 82 for example.

How can I do that?

I've tried with strip_tags from php but when doing that, it also stopping the thing to work because it is removing `<div id="variable"></div>`.

When I click calculate in the window, it will generate "159". I want 159 to be added as value in my weight input.

[image]

The value inside `<div id="variable"></div>` is dynamically generated from a previous jquery code. So `<div id="variable"></div>` starts as `<div id="variable"></div>`, with no value

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to accomplish here

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you mean.  What "is a number like 82 for example"?  Can you provide a more complete (but still minimal) example of what you're trying to do and how you're trying to do it?

Comment: put the number in the div before you put the div into the value-field

Answer (score 2):

Do it from the dom after page loads by getting that text and passing it to input value

```js
$(function(){
  $('#weight').val( $('#variable').text().trim() )
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="weight" id="weight" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Weight" >
<div id="variable">82</div>
```

Comment: This might work but there is a problem. The value inside <div id="variable"></div> is dynamically generated from a previous jquery code. So <div id="variable"></div> starts as <div id="variable"></div>, with no value.

Comment: So you should be able to set both when you generate the value. Show a [mcve] in question

Answer (score 0):

Try using jQuery to set value in the textbox:

## Code

```
$('#weight').val($('#variable').html());
```